# A problem related to connectivity of analytic functions

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $f(z)\in A(\mathbb D)$, where $A(\mathbb D)$ is the space of analytic functions on the open unit disk $\mathbb D$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb D}$.

**Question:** Is the connectivity of $f(\mathbb D)$ finite? If not, what condition should be added to make sure the connectivity of $f(\mathbb D)$ be finite?

**Remark:** when $f(z)$ be a conformal map or a proper map, the connectivity of $f(\mathbb D)$ is $1$.

Comment: Could you please remind me how does one prove $f(\mathbb{D})$ is 1 when $f(z)$ is proper?

Comment: Use the Riemann-Hurwitz Formula: $m-2=k(n-2)+r$

Comment: However, we can prove that the “holes” of $f(\mathbb D)$ are Jordan domains with their boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can be infinite. Start with the function $w=f(z)$ mapping the unit disc onto itself.
Let $I_k$ be disjoint closed arcs on the image disc in the $w$ plane. Deform the image region by adding two "horns" on each $I_k$ which go outside and then overelap. If the size of the horns tends to zero as $k\to\infty$, the function will be continuous.

Comment: It's not clear on adding two "horns" on each $I_k$. Is $I_k$ closed curve or just closed arc?